# How to read from any line

Tags: python, python-3.x, merge

have a directory with files as:

```
ab_list
bd_list
cd_list
mno_list
hk_list 
pd_list
```

I have another file called testfile as outside this directory as:

```
abc
que nw

ab_list   ON   8
gs_list   ON   9
hk_list   OFF  9
bd_list   ON   7
cd_list   OFF  6
fr_list   ON   5
mno_list  ON   4
pq_list   OFF   6
jk_list   ON   7
pd_list   OFF  8
```

I want to compare the 2 and all the files with filename and ON next to it(if matched) their content should get merged into a new file called merge_file. The other files which match with testfile but have OFF, their filenames should be printed in a new_file.

Assuming the directory name is `Folder`, and in that directory is another directory named `folder`, this code does just that:

```
    from glob import glob

    test_file_directory = "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Folder\\"

    files1 = glob("*.txt")
    with open(test_file_directory+"testfile.txt","r") as f:
        files2 = [' '.join([l.split()[0],l.split()[1]]) for l in f.readlines()[3:]]

    for f1 in files1:
        for f2 in files2:
            if f1[:-4]+'   ON' == f2:
                #print('match')
                with open('merge_file.txt','a') as a:
                    with open(f1,'r') as r:
                        a.write(r.read()+'\n')
            elif f1[:-4]+'   OFF' == f2:
                #print('match')
                with open('match_file.txt','a') as a:
                    with open(f1,'r') as r:
                        a.write(f"{f2} {len(r.readlines())}\n")
```

here this code reads the lines of file from 4th line `files2 = [' '.join([l.split()[0],l.split()[1]]) for l in f.readlines()[3:]`, however now I want this code to work in general for all similar kind of files for which it can read from 4th 5th 1st or any line.
When i remove the `[3:]` It gives an error saying  `files2 = [' '.join([l.split()[0],l.split()[1]]) for l in f.readlines()[3:]] index error: list out of range`. can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

If you can help it, you would be better off storing your `testfile.txt` as another file format suitable for this task, such as a [csv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values).

However, I have written this class which should do what you're after; you may need to add in extra conditional checks, for example, it doesn't care if the `merge_list` or `new_file` exists already, it'll just append to them.

```py
import re
import os
class Merge:
    def __init__(self, merge_list_file, merge_dir, merge_file, unmerged_file):
        self.merge_list_file = merge_list_file
        self.merge_dir = merge_dir
        self.merge_file = merge_file
        self.unmerged_file = unmerged_file
        self.__parse_list()

    def __parse_list(self):
        pattern = re.compile(r"^(.+?)\s(ON|OFF)\s+\d+$")
        with open(self.merge_list_file, 'r') as ml:
            content = ml.readlines()
            self.merge_list = [{'file': match.group(1), 'merge': (True if match.group(2) == 'ON' else False)} for line in content for match in [pattern.search(line)] if match]
        return self.merge_list

    def merge(self):
        merge_file = open(self.merge_file, 'a')
        unmerge_file = open(self.unmerged_file, 'a')
        for i in (self.merge_list):
            file = i['file']
            merge = i['merge']
            if not merge:
                unmerge_file.write(file + "\n")
                continue
            to_merge = os.path.join(self.merge_dir, file)
            if not os.path.exists(to_merge):
                continue
            with open(to_merge) as f:
                merge_file.write(f.read())
        merge_file.close()
        unmerge_file.close()
```

And you would use it like so

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Merge('testfile.txt', 'Folder', 'merge_file.txt', 'new_file.txt').merge()
```

Where my structure looks like

```py
C:.
|   merge.py
|   testfile.txt
|
\---Folder
        A
        B
        C
```

Results in `merge_file.txt` containing `AB` (the `A` and `B` contents appended together) and `new_file.txt` containing `C` (the 'OFF' files appended each on a new line).